# Multi-Device Designer Views Not Found in Delphi Project

Tags: delphi, rad-studio, design-view

For some reason, the project that I have been working on no longer allows me to change the 'View' on the Multi-Device View Designer drop downs. I select the 'Style' to be IOS and the 'View' shows me a list of a number of available views (i.e., iPhone 3.5", iPhone 5.5", iPad...). When I select an option, I get an error message 'Item Not Found'.

If I bring up an older version of the app, the views work just fine. I have not been able to identify the difference between the 2 projects with regards to these views. Both projects have the following code in the .pas file.

```
implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.iPhone4in.fmx IOS}
{$R *.iPhone55in.fmx IOS}
```

Nothing shows under the 'Created' Title of the Views but all the options show under the 'Available' Title.

I am using RAD Studio 10.4.2 and RAD Studio 11 on Windows 10 and SQL Server Backend.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?